# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'The UPDATE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Subject_Professor"

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql

So I am writing a C# application and in my database I have a table Subject with columns: SubjectID - PK, ProfessorID - FK, Description, Credits and Name; also a table Professor with columns: ProfessorID - PK, Name, Surname and Salary. I have a problem when I try to update a Subject info and I don't know why. I have set the Update rule to be Cascade. I have tried to find the answer here but couldn't find one.

Here is the command text:

```
command.CommandText = "UPDATE Subject SET ProfessorID = @ProfessorID, Name = @Name, Description = @Description, Credits = @Credits WHERE SubjectID = @SubjectID ";

 
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("ProfessorID",Convert.ToInt32(cb.SelectedValue));
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Name", tbName.Text);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Credits", Convert.ToByte(tbCredits.Text));
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Description", rtb.Text);
```

`if (command.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0) {...}` here I get this error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'The UPDATE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Subject_Professor". The conflict occurred in database "UNI", table "dbo.Professor", column 'ProfessorID'.
> The statement has been terminated.'

Comment: Simple, you are trying to set the `professorid` to a value which doesn't exist in the `professor` table. Try running it in SSMS with sample data you know is correct.

Comment: @DaleK oh I see now, what a silly mistake.. Thank You!